# how to pass props in react typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm working on a react typescript app,
inn react if I have an array of products, I can map each product to a component by passing down a single product as a props

```
 products = [{_id: 1, name: 'product1'},{_id: 1, name: 'product2'}{_id: 3, name: 'product3'}]

products.map(product => (<Product product={product} />)
```

I need to do the same in react typescript but I'm getting this error

> Type '{ product: CartItemType; handleAddToCart: () => null; }' is not
> assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props & { children?:
> ReactNode; }'.   Property 'product' does not exist on type
> 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props & { children?: ReactNode; }'.  TS2322

here is my code

```
    import { useState } from 'react';
import { useQuery } from 'react-query'
 
import Item from './item/item'


// Types
export type CartItemType = {
  id: number;
  category: string;
  description: string;
  image: string;
  price: number;
  title: string;
  amount: number;
}
 
const fetchProducts = async ():Promise<CartItemType[]> => {
  const res = await fetch("https://fakestoreapi.com/products");
  return res.json();
};


function App() { 
  const { data, isLoading, error, status } = useQuery<CartItemType[]>("products", fetchProducts);
  console.log(data); 
  
  const handleAddToCart = () => null;
  
  return (
    <div>
      {data?.map((product)=>( 
          // my error is on this line, product 
          <Item product={product} handleAddToCart={handleAddToCart}/> 
      )) 
      } 
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Product` component needs to know a list of all props, you can create a separate type for that:

```
type Props = {
// your types here
}
```

After you can simply use this type:

```
export const Product: React.FC<Props> = props => { //your code here }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the type for Item component to accept props product, handleAddToCart.
In your Item component, type should be like below:

```
interface ItemProps {
  product: CartItemType,
  handleAddToCart: () => null
}

export const Item = (props: ItemProps) => {
  // your Item component implementation
};
```